# How can I dynamically call the named route in a :partial in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, routes

I have the following partial.  It can be called from three different times in a view as follows:

```
 <%= render :partial => "contact_event",
     :collection => @contacts,
        :locals => {:event => email} %>
```

Second time:

```
 <%= render :partial => "contact_event",
     :collection => @contacts,
        :locals => {:event => call} %>
```

Third time:

```
 <%= render :partial => "contact_event",
     :collection => @contacts,
        :locals => {:event => letter} %>
```

In each instance, call, email, letter refer to a specific instance of a Model Call, Email, or Letter.

**Here is what I tried to do and conceptually what I'd like to do: assign the route based on the class name that has been passed to the :event from the :partial**.

What I did was create what the actual url should be.  The 'text' of it is correct, but doesn't seem to recognize it as a named route.

```
 <!-- provide a link to skip this item -->
 <% url = "skip_contact_#{event.class.name.tableize.singularize}_url" %>
 <%= link_to_remote "Skip #{url} Remote",
    :url => send("#{url}(contact_event, event)")
    :update => "update-area-#{contact_event.id}-#{event.id}" %>
 <span id='update-area-<%="#{contact_event.id}-#{event.id}"%>'> </span>
```

The result of the above:  when event has been passed an email instance, for example, it says:

> skip_contact_email_url not a method.

The url is right, but it doesn't recognize as a method.

1. How can I dynamically define skip_contact_email_url to be skip_contact_letter_url if the local variable is letter?
2. Even better, how can I have a single named route that would do the appropriate action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [polymorphic_url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url). It generates corresponding route based on item types:

**Edit:** The route is generated based on record's class, so if you pass `:event => call` or `:event => email`, it will work like this:

```
# event.class == Email
polymorphic_url([contact_event, event], :action => :skip)
#=> /contact_events/:contact_event_id/emails/:id/skip

# event.class == Call
polymorphic_url([contact_event, event], :action => :skip)
#=> /contact_events/:contact_event_id/calls/:id/skip
```

etc.

**Edit2:**
Routes:

```
map.resources :contacts do |contact|
  contact.with_options :member => {:skip => : ... [get/post - what you have] } do |c|
    c.resources :letter
    c.resources :emails
    c.resources :calls
  end
end
```

Comment: the value for event is coming through the :locals hash

Comment: Yes, you assign any ActiveRecord object as `:event`, and then use it. See edit.

Comment: okay this is interesting -- it's spinning my head just a little bit, though...but I think this is the way to do it.  How do I create the routes, though to make this work?

Comment: oh wait, so if I make emails, calls nested into a class called contact_events...is that the idea....?  I currently don't really have a concept of "contact_event" -- I use that to store the instance of Contact...

Comment: See edit for routes. I assume you have classes `Contact`, `Email`, `Letter` and `Call` and controllers `EmailsController`, `LettersController`, `CallsController`.